# PHPMailer don't sending email to google

Tags: phpmailer

PHPMailer don't sending email to gmail.
But to other hosting its work.

No errors in debug.
No other email its work.

Im using ovh smtp but website is in other hosting.

```
// Config
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Host       = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'email';
$mail->Password   = 'password';

// Header
$mail->setFrom('email');
$mail->addAddress('email');

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is an email test';
$mail->Body    = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint     occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

try {
    // Send
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Im try use ssl, other ports and manage domain dns.

Comment: Gmail will not accept messages unless there is a valid `DKIM`, valid `DMARC` and valid `reverse DNS` for said domain ..  Just a random server sending emails is bound to be blocked by more than just Google ...

Comment: @Zak I have DKIM and DMARC on cloudflare.

Comment: Adding to @Zak. Starting from February 2024...

Comment: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ Do you have a PTR?

Comment: Yes i have PTR. 
By domain: modernrpg.pl
SMTP: smtp.modernrpg.pl

Comment: Have you tried something like Glockapps to make sure you're not on a blacklist and that your messages aren't "spammy" ?